# Why "face by" in the following

Tags: grammar, expressions

In one of today's nydailynews headlines, the writer writes the following:

> India reminds world of cross-border terror **faced by** Kabul.

The **face by** usage doesn't seem to convey the right meaning here because it assumes that Kabul is the performer or initiator of the action. However, that doesn't seem to be the case as the article goes on to state:

> Tokyo, July 8 — In a veiled reference to Pakistan, India Sunday told the international community of the "existential threat" Afghanistan faces from terrorism emanating from across its borders.

Is this the right usage?

Comment: It is in Passive Voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s the passive form of *India reminds world of cross-border terror that Kabul faces.* Nothing unusual about it.

Comment: Omm, I see. How do we know it's the passive? Hints?

Comment: Past participle followed by 'by' is a rough guide.

Answer (score 0):

It is commmon in newspaper headlines to omit the verb *be* in passive sentences.

Murder Suspect [is] Arrested.
Binkleys Bank Reported to Regulator.
High Street Plan Rejected
Forest Sell-off Bid Aborted.
Three killed by lightning.